# VisualStudio bug?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, winforms

In VS 2010 created a new `WinForm` project. Added a new UserControl WPF.

2 compile-time errors appeared:

> Error 1   The type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.IQueryAmbient'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference
>   to assembly 'System.Xaml,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. D:\Projets\WindowsFormsApplication2\UserControl1.xaml.cs    20  26  WindowsFormsApplication2
>
> Error 2   The type name
>   'IComponentConnector' could not be
>   found in the namespace
>   'System.Windows.Markup'. This type has
>   been forwarded to assembly
>   'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   Consider adding a reference to that
>   assembly. D:\Projets\WindowsFormsApplication2\obj\x86\Debug\UserControl1.g.cs 41  100 WindowsFormsApplication2

**NB.**

References like `PresenationCore.dll`, `PresenationFramework.dll`, `WindowsBase.dll` are added automatically when adding a new WPF UserControl to the WinForm project, so why not `System.Xaml.dll` too?

==============

Bug reported on **[Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/629731/not-all-references-are-added-when-addind-a-wpf-usercontrol-to-a-winform-project)**.

Comment: Well as it says, consider adding a reference to System.Xaml.

Comment: @mdm Why should I not add then `PresenationCore.dll`, `PresenationFramework.dll`, `WindowsBase.dll`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

it sounds like you just need a reference to `System.Xaml.dll`

---

Re whether this is a bug in VS; well, I suppose the templates *could* add that reference - I can reproduce it, so it may be worth [logging on connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)

Comment: Yes, but why that references are not added automatically with the WPF Conrtol, like PresentationCore, by eg.

Comment: @serhio - you edited the question, I think; originally there was something noting the guid and wondering *how to fix it*.

Comment: Old shit i know, but im h.aving this problem nw, but I have all DLLs referenced...

Answer (score 11):

Was this project migrated from .NET 3.5 to NET 4.0 ? If yes, the interface now resides in System.Xaml and you need to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case "System.Xaml" was added to the project automatically but giving the same type of error:

> The type name 'IComponentConnector' could not be found in the
>   namespace 'System.Windows.Markup'. This type has been forwarded to
>   assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,....
>   .' Consider adding a reference to that
>   assembly.

I've solved the problem by, just deleting the "System.Xaml" from *References* and again adding "System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0" from *Framework*.